# Return month name in specified locale

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, locale

Using `date_format` we can extract month name from a date:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2021-05-01',),('2021-06-01',)], ['c1']).select(F.col('c1').cast('date'))
df = df.withColumn('month', F.date_format('c1', 'LLLL'))
df.show()
#+----------+-----+
#|        c1|month|
#+----------+-----+
#|2021-05-01|  May|
#|2021-06-01| June|
#+----------+-----+
```

It's in English, but I would like to get it in French.

I have found that Spark **is aware** of month names in French!

```py
spark.sql("select to_csv(named_struct('date', date '1970-06-01'), map('dateFormat', 'LLLL', 'locale', 'FR'))").show()
#+---------------------------------------------+
#|to_csv(named_struct(date, DATE '1970-06-01'))|
#+---------------------------------------------+
#|                                         juin|
#+---------------------------------------------+
```

But I cannot find a way to make `date_format` to accept another locale. How can these functionalities be joined to make the following result?

```
+----------+-----+
|        c1|month|
+----------+-----+
|2021-05-01|  mai|
|2021-06-01| juin|
+----------+-----+
```

Comment: try looking at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67461812/9477843). For another locales, the language tags are in IETF BCP 47 format, [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/language_tags.php) are some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this clever guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9477843), this is a very nice solution to return results in another language (locale):

```py
df = df.withColumn('month', F.to_csv(F.struct('c1'), {'dateFormat': 'LLLL', 'locale': 'fr'}))

df.show()
#+----------+-----+
#|        c1|month|
#+----------+-----+
#|2021-05-01|  mai|
#|2021-06-01| juin|
#+----------+-----+
```